# How to do this Apache mod-rewrite redirect transparently

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this redirect (in Apache 2.4 VirtualHost *:80 configurations), which redirects example.com over to example.com/api/ (subfolder) and it works flawlessly.

Once I enter http://example.com into the browser, it takes me directly to http://example.com/api/.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /api$1 [R,L]
```

Now, what I need is for this to work transparently. I want http://example.com/api to load directly on the root domain: http://example.com

I've tried all kinds of suggestions I found on the internet, but nothing that would hide/mask the subfolder from the final URL that shows in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I figured there is an easier solution to this. I am running my app on a Tomcat server behind Apache and thus adding the following to Apache rules into VirtualHost config fixed the issue with subfolder transparency.

```
ProxyAddHeaders off
ProxyPass / http://server-host-for-example-com:8080/connect/
ProxyPassReverse / http://server-host-for-example-com:8080/connect/
```